# How to register OpenRCE?

Tags: reverse

When I register OpenRCE, it shows

> Too much spam, too little content. Find an admin for the 'secret' to complete registration if you really want. At some point, the site is going to get a complete refresh.

and after click the register button, it shows that human not detected.
How can I deal with it?

Comment: Yes better not to create new topic.. same situation for me. Any hope of help.

Answer (score 4):

The secret is 'openrce-2014'.
I got it from Pedram's answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/3rxj78/need_some_help_to_register_to_openrce/)